# Download full size image using Selenium

Tags: image, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, urllib

Using the code below I can download images from google without opening the image. Therefore the image is downloaded in lower quality but i want to download it full size.

```
 #Opens up Google
        browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
        search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
        search.send_keys(name,Keys.ENTER)

 #goes to images
        elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Images')
        elem.get_attribute('href')
        elem.click()

 #gets images
        elem1 = browser.find_element_by_id('islmp')

 #gets the first image
        sub = elem1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img')
        sub.get_attribute('href')
        sub.click()

 #here i tried to click on the image and open it, so I can download that large version. But it still downloads the smaller size.
        elem1 = browser.find_element_by_id('islmp')
        sub1=elem1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img')

#create download folder
        try:
            os.mkdir('downloads')
        except FileExistsError:
            pass

#download sub1
        src = sub1.get_attribute('src')
        try:
            if src != None:
                src  = str(src)
                print(src)
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, os.path.join('downloads',barcode+'.jpg'))
            else:
                raise TypeError
        except TypeError:
            print('fail')'''
```

So instead of downloading the first image on the page directly, I want to open the image first, and download the larger image appearing on the right of the page when you click on an image.

Comment: sub1=elem1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img')    this  line works for opening the image, but still it doesnt download this. it downloads small version instead

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `time.sleep(3)` after clicking on sub